# How to get user information when authenticating with OneDrive SDK

Tags: azure-mobile-services, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I am building an Azure App Service that has both Windows Desktop (not UWP) and iOS clients. I want to use Microsoft Account Authentication to authenticate users.

As a result of a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797280/desktop-client-flow-for-microsoftaccount-access-to-azure-mobile-service-api/45808264?noredirect=1#comment79052112_45808264) I can now authenticate users using the OneDrive SDK but have fallen at the next hurdle. The One Drive SDK does not appear to provide access to user details such as their given name and email address.

Please can someone point me in the direction of an example or instructions for authenticating a user from an old school desktop application to allow them to access an Azure App Service using their Microsoft Account (NOT Azure AD) that will also provide the client with access to their email address and which does not use depreciated technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After authentication via **Easy Auth**, we can acquire the user information from the `me` endpoint(`https://{yourSiteName}/.auth/me`) by invoking the API like code below:

```
var result =await client.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/me");
```

And to acquire the email, we need the `wl.emails` scope when we authenticate with the OneDrive SDK. And after that we can get the given-name and emails from `me` endpoint like:

```
string email=(string)result[0].SelectToken("$.user_claims[?(@.typ == 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress')]")["val"]

string givenName=(string)result[0].SelectToken("$.user_claims[?(@.typ == 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname')]")["val"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Where would I have found this information documented?

Comment: You can refer the [document](Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service) about easy auth. And also cgillum wrote a series of help blogs about it.(refer [here](https://cgillum.tech/category/easy-auth/))