# Microsoft Graph-API and Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Mobile App and want to use the Microsoft Graph-API for Authentication.
I am using the Microsoft.Identity.Client Namespace. I can acquire a token there by calling

```
authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(_scopes);
```

When I pass this token to my Mobile-App by calling

```
azureUser = await App.MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
```

I receive a MobileServiceInvalidOperationException"You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

I have registered my app in the Application Registration Portal.
[Registration Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGaGY.png)

in Azure it looks like this:
[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsbNg.png)

What di I wrong???

Kind regards,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Easy Auth doesn't support exchange the token using the access token issued from Azure AD V2.0(In this case used MSAL library).

To use the client flow for the mobile client, you can use the OneDrive authentication library to acquire the token from endpoint for Microsoft Account. 
Here is a similar thread for your reference:

[Desktop client flow for MicrosoftAccount access to Azure Mobile Service API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797280/desktop-client-flow-for-microsoftaccount-access-to-azure-mobile-service-api/45808264#45808264)

And below is the code works well for me:

```
public  async Task TestEasyAuthAsync()
{

    string acess_token = await AcquireTokenForLiveAccount();
    string applicationUrl = "https://mobilefei.azurewebsites.net/";
    var mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient(applicationUrl);

    JObject token = new JObject();
    token.Add("access_token", acess_token);
    var user = await mobileClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, token);
    Console.WriteLine($"UserID:\n{user.UserId}");

    var result = await mobileClient.InvokeApiAsync(@"/.auth/me");
    Console.Read();
}

public async  Task<string> AcquireTokenForLiveAccount()
{
    var msAuth = new MsaAuthenticationProvider("57336bd5-a80f-4b48-a29a-07fdea6ef91e", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient", new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access" });
    await msAuth.AuthenticateUserAsync();
    return msAuth.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
You made my day! It works! thank you very much!
One more question :-( I need to confirm the access of this rights:
automatic logon, always information access ,base profile  for the App, every time I log in. how  can it be stored?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: The issue seems that relative to the type of app register. To fix this issue, you can register an **Live SDK applications** instead of **Converged applications**. Then you can use the `public MsaAuthenticationProvider(string clientId, string clientSecret, string returnUrl, string[] scopes, CredentialCache credentialCache);` to new a `MsaAuthenticationProvider` class with providing the secret.